# How to avoid instanceof and casting interface to class

Tags: java

I'd like to avoid instanceof and casting interface to class. I have method with parameter of interface `FFF` and depending on whether `fff` is class `AAA` or `TTT` I call appropriate private method. In one of these methods I have to call `fff.methodSpecificForOnlyOneImplementationOfInterfaceFFF`

I have entities:

```
public interface FFF {
    Long getShipperId();

    default void updatePermissions(final Permissions permissions) {
        ...
        this.setPermissions(permissions);
    }
}

public class AAA implements FFF {
    private TTT Window;
    public TTT getWindow();
}

public class TTT implements FFF {
    
}
```

And I have Service:

```
public class MyService() {
    private Service service; // injected using Spring Boot

public void updatePermissions(FFF fff) {
        final SomeClass someVariable;
        if (fff instanceof TTT) {
            someVariable = Optional.ofNullable(...)
                    .map(...)
                    .orElseGet(() -> createDefaultSettings(fff.getShipperId()));
        } else {
            someVariable= Optional.ofNullable(...)
                    .map(...)
                    .orElseGet(() -> returnPermissions(forwardable));
        }
        fff.updatePermissions(someVariable);
}

private createDefaultSettings(Long id){
    final Settings settings= service.getSettings(shipperId);
        return new Permissions(settings.getDefault(), false);
}

private returnPermissions(FFF fff) {
    AAA aaa= (AAA) fff;
        return Optional.ofNullable(aaa.getWindow()) // There is no getWindow() in FFF interface
                .map(Window::getPermissions)
                .map(...)
                .orElseGet(() -> createDefaultSettings(aaa.getShipperId()));
}
```

How to avoid `instanceof` and casting `AAA aaa= (AAA) fff;`? Or maybe that's ok? Maybe there is better solution for it?

Maybe should I add getTimeWindow() method to FFF interface? Then TTT class have to implement this unnecessary for TTT method

Comment: Move the logic into the concrete implementations so it knows how to update itself when  `fff.updatePermissions()` (no parameter) is invoked.  see also: strategy pattern

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [Strategy design pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern).

Encapsulate logic specific to `AAA` and `TTT` to the separate classes under the `FFF` interface.

```java
public interface FFF {
    void updatePermission();
    SomeVariable getSomeVariable();
}
```

And then concrete implementations:

```java
public class AAA implements FFF {
    public void updatePermission() {
        SomeVariable someVariable = getSomeVariable();
        // do smth specific for AAA
    }

    public SomeVariable getSomeVariable() {
        return new SomeVariableAAA();
    }
}

public class TTT implements FFF {
    public void updatePermission() {
        SomeVariable someVariable = getSomeVariable();
        // do smth specific for TTT
    }

    public SomeVariable getSomeVariable() {
        return new SomeVariableTTT();
    }
}
```

So finally, you are able to replace your `if...else` with call a method.

```java
public void updatePermission(FFF fff) {
    fff.updatePermission();
}
```

Comment: I added sth to createDefaultSettings()  - I use there service so I can't move this logic with service to AAA entity

Comment: I do not want to solve this issue for you. You should update this snippet to your requirements. Do use Decorator patters as well.

Comment: True, that's the solution. I moved logic to AAA and TTT with my service as parameter